# Vetores, ponteiros e armazenamento na memória

Tags: c, ponteiro, array

Preciso resolver um exercício onde preciso usar ponteiros, vetores e armazenamento na memória:

> Crie um vetor com n elementos, sendo que cada posição do vetor
>   corresponderá a um ponteiro para um valor do tipo `float`. Faça a
>   leitura de n valores e armazene-os na memória.

Creio que não seja muito complexo, mas ainda estou estudando o assunto e seria bom ter este exercício resolvido para ver como as coisas funcionam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi é isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main () {
       int  n, i;
       float *v; // Declaração do vetor
       scanf ("%d", &n); 
       v = malloc (n * sizeof (float)); // Alocação do vetor em n elementos
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf ("%f", &v[i]); // Leitura e armazenamento dos valores na memoria
       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf ("%f ", v[i]); // Teste
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado por ter me ajudado, cara! Eu estava em dúvida quanto ao uso do malloc e de como ele gostaria de que fizesse o ponteiro, pois depois de tantos slides explicando, ainda me faltou pegar a ~essência~ do negócio. Com este exemplo as coisas parecem mais claras. Tenho mais 24 exercícios para dar continuidade agora, obrigado!